# 'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, docker

I have installed docker in my windows machine using 'pip install docker' command but system is unable to figure out the existence of docker though added in environment variables (pip docker path).

Added path (Environment variables): C:\Users\Name\foo\local\boo\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\docker

**'docker' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

There are lots of similar questions posted in this forum but apparently they did not help my case so for.

Could someone assist?

Comment: you installed python library for docker, you can use it from within python: `import docker` 
You haven't installed `docker` this way.

Have a look at: https://pypi.org/project/docker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You installed the Docker module for python, but you haven't installed Docker on your Windows machine.  If you're wanting to run Docker on your machine, follow [these](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) directions from the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Using pip you have installed a Python library for the Docker Engine API ,  (most probably this one: https://pypi.org/project/docker/).

Docker is a containerisation technology, installation guide: [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#:~:text=Install%20Docker%20Desktop%20on%20Windows,get%20it%20from%20Docker%20Hub.)

Answer (score -1):

Try restarting windows and check if the error still continues. I had this error once and as incredible as it seems it solved my problem. I hope it helps, friend. Or try this command in CMD: `refreshenv`